# Working with an old SQLite2 database

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlite2

I have a really old, dusty SQLite 2 database lying around on my hard disk that I'd like to search around in.

So far, I've tried opening it with tools such as sqliteman, sqlitebrowser, and simply trying to open it with `sqlite3` in Python, but to no avail.

All tools now seem to exclusively support SQLite 3.

Is there a way I can open this old SQLite 2 database in Python?

By the way, I'm pretty sure it's a SQLite database, looking around in the binary contents:

```
user@host:~ $ head -1 old.db | cut -c 1-48
** This file contains an SQLite 2.1 database **
```

Comment: Why dont you compile an older version of sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source code and go back to an older version.

I found [a version_2 branch](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/timeline?r=version_2) by just surfing around their site. Clicking the newest commit takes you to [a page](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/info/47fee16ba9) where you can download a tarball of the code at that time.